# Haskell function type not what expected

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, fold

I am trying to write a function to compute the inner product of 2 lists, i.e. if the lists are [1,2,3] and [4,5,6] then the inner product would be (1 x 4) + (2 x 5) + (3 x 6) = 4 + 10 + 18 = 32.

So I thought to use `zipWith` to obtain the products, and then `foldl` to sum them with addition. So `zipWith` should produce [4, 10, 18] and then the `foldl` should sum it to 32.

So I have written:

```
innerprod [] [] = 0
innerprod x y = foldl (+) 0 (zipWith (*) x y)
```

Everything compiles but when I run in ghci:

```
Prelude ListFuncs> innerprod [1,2,3] [4,5,6]

<interactive>:3:1:
     No instance for (Num
                       ([c0] -> (a0 -> b0 -> a0) -> a0 -> [b0] -> a0))
      arising from a use of `innerprod'
     Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (Num ([c0] -> (a0 -> b0 -> a0) -> a0 -> [b0] -> a0))
     In the expression: innerprod [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6]
     In an equation for `it': it = innerprod [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6]
```

I tried making the code like this due to the error message, but it returns a different error at compile time:

```
innerprod :: Num [Int] => (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> [Int] -> Int
innerprod [] [] = 0
innerprod x y = foldl + 0 (zipWith (*) x y)
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? I would have though the signature would be `innerprod :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int` since it takes 2 int lists and returns an int. But that does not work either. Thank you for your time. Please let me know if I should not have asked this question here.

Comment: Your first function is correct (works as expected). I cannot reproduce the error. Your second function requires parenthesis around the `(+)`.

Comment: BTW, `foldl` is evil. Always use either its strict equivalent `foldl'` (you need to `import Data.List`), or (if you want a lazy fold) `foldr`. Also note, your base case `innerprod [] []` is unnecessary, because both `zipWith` and `foldl'` can correctly deal with empty lists.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thank you for your answer I don't believe the problem was my leaving the parentheses out!

Comment: @user2407038 I am embarassed to say the issue was due to my not parenthesizing foldl correctly!

Comment: Use `sum` instead of rolling your own summation.  Also, the empty lists are not a special case.  So `innerProd x y = sum $ zipWith (*) x y`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Num [Int] => (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> [Int] -> Int` is a complete bogus signature. It means this: "provided any list of integers can be treated as a single number [??!], I give you a specialised version of a fold". That's no way like what you want an inner product to work, namely `Vector -> Vector -> Scalar`; in this case `Num a => [a] -> [a] -> a`. Indeed, with that signature your original definition works flawlessly:

```
innerProd :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> a
innerProd x y = foldl' (+) 0 (zipWith (*) x y)
```

> ListFuncs*> innerProd [1,2,3][4,5,6]
>   32

I think you have *not* actually tried this one. What you have written was without the parens around `+`.

```
               foldl + 0 (zipWith (*) x y)
```

Now, that is quite another beast. It means, you add the `foldl`-function to what you get by applying the `0` function to the zip of the lists... another obvious-bogus thing. Remember that infix operators bind different from normal function application, you need to pack them in parens to pass them as a function argument.